# Preparing a Latex document with Bengali Language

Tags: latex

I want to prepare a document with Bengali Language

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_language

I used texmacs but it didn't support Bengali Language.What editor should I use for writing Latex Documents in Bengali?

Comment: Just to note: [Tex StackExchange](tex.stackexchange.com) also welcomes posts on editors and other Tex related software. In fact, it already had a question and answer on  [how to write Bengali in Latex]( http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99606/14210)